# Context menus in Chrome extensions

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I've searched and searched and searched for a solution to this but every source I come across seems to assume I already have profound knowledge of Chrome extensions, even Google's help pages

I know the very basics of Chrome extensions and I made one with some basic content scripts. However, now I'm looking to make one that involves context menus.

Let's say when you highlight words and right-click them, you see the option `Search '<highlighted words>' on Google` and when clicked, it opens `http://www.google.com/search?q=<highlighted words>` in a new tab. I know this exists in Chrome and I'm sure there have been a billion extensions replicating it, but this is only an example for me to build off of.

How can I do this?

Comment: you missed this tutorial, it's exactly your question http://tomoprogramming.blogspot.fr/2013/08/simple-tutorial-for-chrome-extension.html

Comment: The question was published in 2012. The tutorial on 2013. Can't miss something that didn't exist.

Answer (score 80, accepted):

Script should look like this:

```
function getword(info,tab) {
  console.log("Word " + info.selectionText + " was clicked.");
  chrome.tabs.create({  
    url: "http://www.google.com/search?q=" + info.selectionText
  });
}
chrome.contextMenus.create({
  title: "Search: %s", 
  contexts:["selection"], 
  onclick: getword
});
```

And manifest.json:

```
{
    "name": "App name",
    "version": "1.0",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "description": "Your description",
    "permissions": [
      "contextMenus"
     ],
    "background": { 
      "scripts": ["script.js"]
    }
}
```

Here you have how to load extension: http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/getstarted.html

Comment: Put those two files (manifest.json and script.js) into one folder. That's all!

Comment: This answer is from 2012. It's 2018 now and I notice that `chrome.contextMenus` is undefined in content-scripts now, it only works in background scripts.

Comment: I've added a new answer fixing the errors contained in Bartlomiej Szalach's and in anhquan's answers.

Comment: chrome no longer supports adding v2 manifests.

Answer (score 33):

The answer from Bartlomiej Szalach is too old. It will not work on Chrome Version 80.0.3987.163 (April 2020).

According to the documentation,

> onclick: A function that is called back when the menu item is clicked. Event pages cannot use this; instead, they should register a listener for contextMenus.onClicked.

The background.js should be modified as follows:

```js
const CONTEXT_MENU_ID = "MY_CONTEXT_MENU";
function getword(info,tab) {
  if (info.menuItemId !== CONTEXT_MENU_ID) {
    return;
  }
  console.log("Word " + info.selectionText + " was clicked.");
  chrome.tabs.create({  
    url: "http://www.google.com/search?q=" + info.selectionText
  });
}
chrome.contextMenus.create({
  title: "Search: %s", 
  contexts:["selection"], 
  id: CONTEXT_MENU_ID
});
chrome.contextMenus.onClicked.addListener(getword)
```

Comment: A good answer, but I'm pretty sure Chrome will throw because `chrome.contextMenus.create` will be called on each invocation of background script which (considering the same ID is used on each invocation) will result in an error.

Comment: i have context menu option based on that i want to open chrom extension popup, how can i do that?

Answer (score 15):

Improving on ahnquan's answer so `chrome.contextMenus.create` isn't called on every background script invocation, and also encoding the `highlighted text` into URI so it doesn't break when it contains special characters, such as `;,/?:@&=+$`.

Your background.js will look like:

```js
chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(() =>
    chrome.contextMenus.create({
        title: 'Search Google for "%s"',
        contexts: ["selection"],
        id: "myContextMenuId",
    })
);
    
chrome.contextMenus.onClicked.addListener((info, tab) =>
    chrome.tabs.create({
        url: `https://www.google.com/search?q=${encodeURIComponent(info.selectionText)}` 
    })
);
```

manifest.json (MV2):

```json
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "App name",
    "version": "1.0",
    
    "permissions": ["contextMenus"],
    "background": { 
        "scripts": ["background.js"],
        "persistent": false
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Manifest v3 is out so to improve on Lucas Mendonca's answer, you just change the manifest.json to:

```json
{
    "manifest_version": 3,
    "name": "App name",
    "version": "1.0",
    "permissions": ["contextMenus"],
    "background": { 
        "service_worker": "background.js"
    }
}
```

Comment: The "background.persistent" key cannot be used with manifest_version 3. Use the "background.service_worker" key instead.

Manifest V3 no longer supports background pages. Instead it now supports a new feature called service workers.

The key background in your manifest.json can no longer contain the field persistent, and also update the value from scripts to service_worker. Service worker cannot contain an array but can only contain a single string value.

Please check for validity of your answer before answering.