# Add more custom option for a chrome extension context menu

Tags: google-chrome-extension

Is there any way to add custom options to the extension context menu, when user right clicks on extension in the chrome. Any inputs would be appreciated. 
[image]

Update
Sample page action extension I tried

```
Manifest.json
   {
       "name": "Sample",
       "version": "0.1",
       "manifest_version": 2,
       "background": {
        "scripts": ["background.js"]
       },
       "page_action": {
        "default_title": "Sample"
        },
        "permissions": [
        "contextMenus"
        ]
    }
```

Background.js

```
chrome.contextMenus.create({
    title: "Option22",
    contexts: ["page_action"],
    onclick: function() {
        console.log("click");
    }
});

chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(function() {
  // Replace all rules ...
  chrome.declarativeContent.onPageChanged.removeRules(undefined, function() {
    // With a new rule ...
    chrome.declarativeContent.onPageChanged.addRules([
      {
        // That fires when a page's URL contains a 'g' ...
        conditions: [
          new chrome.declarativeContent.PageStateMatcher({
            pageUrl: { urlContains: 'g' },
          })
        ],
        // And shows the extension's page action.
        actions: [ new chrome.declarativeContent.ShowPageAction() ]
      }
    ]);
  });
});
```

Comment: @Haibara Ai: I believe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13783500/context-menus-in-chrome-extensions) question is about context menu of a browser. My question is about context menu of an extension.

Comment: sorry for misunderstanding that, I have posted an answer for "browser action", you could have a try.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please check [contextMenus](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contextMenus), you could create the extension context menu by setting context `"browser_action"`

manifest.json

```
{
    "name": "36715370",
    "version": "0.1",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "background": {
        "scripts": ["background.js"]
    },
    "browser_action": {
        "default_title": "Your browser action title"
    },
    "permissions": [
        "contextMenus"
    ]
}
```

background.js

```
chrome.contextMenus.create({
    title: "Your title here",
    contexts: ["browser_action"],
    onclick: function() {
        console.log("click");
    }
});
```

Comment: I believe this about context menu of a browser. My question is about context menu of an extension(Right click on the extension icon).

Comment: @SarathChand, this answer is for "right click on the extension icon", you could have a try.

Comment: @ Haibara Ai: Did you get chance to try the same for page action extension? I tried and is not working... Or any inputs?

Comment: @SarathChand, when you are saying "not working", what do you mean? The contextMenu is not created after you change browser_action to page_action in both two files?

Comment: @SarathChand You don't have `"declarativeContent"` permission, and your whole code just errors out. I also suspect that your custom menu will only show up if the page action is "shown".

Comment: @SarathChand, so could you check your code and errors again?

Comment: @Haibara Ai: Adding declarativeContent worked... Thank you