# Right-click context menu for Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to create a right-click context menu for Chrome.
I want to be able to highlight text, right click, then click to open a new tab using a URL determined by the highlighted text.

I have a manifest (though I'm not sure I've done the background part right):

```
  {
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "ClickMenu",
    "version": "1.0",

    "description": "A right-click context menu",
    "icons": {
        "16": "icons/icon-16.png",
        "48": "icons/icon-48.png",
        "128": "icons/icon-128.png"
    },

    "permissions": [ "contextMenus" ],

    "background": {
        "scripts": ["contextMenu.js"],
        "persistent": false
        }
    }
```

And a contextMenu.js:

```
    function MenuContext(contextInfo, tab) {
    chrome.tabs.create({
    'url' : 'https://myurl.com/' + contextInfo.selectionText + '/launch'
    });
}

    var contextId = chrome.contextMenus.create({
        'title' : 'Launch this',
        'contexts' : [
          'selection'
        ],
        'onclick' : MenuContext
    });
```

It's not working. I can load the extension, but there's no context menu or functionality.

Can you see what I've done wrong?

Comment: This seems to work for me. [Context menus in Chrome extensions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13783500/context-menus-in-chrome-extensions)

Answer (score 1):

You create an event page (bacause in your manifest you define `"persistent": false`).

In event page you to do three changes when you create context menu item.

1. Pass a string id parameter.
2. Use the `chrome.contextMenus.onClicked` callback instead of an onclick parameter.
3. Create them in `chrome.runtime.onInstalled` event.

For more information - [Event pages best practices](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/event_pages#best-practices).

(By the way - in event page don't save data in variables).

(I'm sorry about my english...)